# Domain of $\ln(\ln(\ln(x)))$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

So my problem states,

> Find the Domain and Derivative of the Function $$\ln(\ln(\ln(x))).$$

I know that I can just use the chain rule to find the derivative, but to find the domain, I don't know. All I know is that I need to use the identity $$e^{\ln x}=x.$$

Answer (score 6):

You need $\ln \ln x$ to be positive for $\ln \ln \ln x$ to be real, which means $\ln x $ has to be greater than $1$ , which means that $x > e$.

As for derivatives, use the chain rule and $\frac{d}{dx} \ln x = \frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: Yup. Thank You. I understand it now

Answer (score 2):

1. domain - ln(ln x)) > 0 => ln x > 1 => x > e
2. derivative - chain rule: $\frac{d}{dx}  (\ln(\ln(\ln (x)))) =  \frac{1}{(\ln(\ln(x)))} * \frac{1}{\ln(x)} * \frac{1}{x}$